# I want to learn how to make USB drive

Tags: usb

I would like to learn the process of USB manufacturing. I am a software engineer and have a little idea about embedded C and arduino, but I don't know what EXACTLY I should be using. Please would you let me know about the process. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please address the _Tour_ of the site and related content. This will give you an idea what kind of questions we answer here.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of "USB drive" you are talking about? For a USB flash drive you'll need a USB controller and a Nand flash, or a USB-to-SD controller (USB card reader ICs are very cheap today) and a (micro)SD card. For a more custom solution you'll need USB capable microcontroller and quite a lot of software development.